# unrecognized bytes python when convert overflow int to bytes

Tags: python, arrays, byte, overflow

I know how declare `bytes`
I used to use hexadecimal notation like this

```
bita = b'\x01\x02'
```

I was trying run this simple code

```
overflow_int = 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999

bita= int.to_bytes(overflow_int,length=(overflow_int.bit_length()+7)//8,byteorder='big')

print(bita) 
print(len(bita))
print(bita[0])
print(b'\np'[0])
print(int.from_bytes(bita,byteorder='big'))
```

it gave me output

```
b'\np\xc3\xc4\nd\xe6\xc5\x19\x99\t\x0be\xf6}\x92?\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
23
10
10
999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

In first index of bita, Yes I know why `10` because `\n` in `ascii` means `newline` which it's unprintable ascii and `10th` ascii char.

But why `b'\np' ==  b'\n'`. Why it includes `p`? What does it means? Not only that but also symbol-symbol non-alpanumeric like `?{`.
Also why `len(bita) == 23`?

Comment: It's not `\np`. It is `\n` followed by the character `p`. `\n` is one byte, `p` is another byte.

Comment: I see.., ```p``` is printable ascii

Comment: Yes. same with `{` and `?`